# Retrieve a List of Objects from another object stored in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've searched a lot of posts in order to find a solution, but i couldn't find one.
I have 2 classes a Recipe class:

```
public class Recepta {
private String nom;
private List<Ingredient> ingredients;
private List<String> pasos;

public Recepta() {
}

public Recepta(String nom,List<Ingredient> ingredients, List<String> pasos) {
    this.nom = nom;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.pasos = pasos;
}
//Getter and setters
}
```

and my Ingredient class:

```
public class Ingredient {
private String nom;
private String quantitat;

public Ingredient(){
}

public Ingredient(String nom,String quantitat){
    this.nom = nom;
    this.quantitat = quantitat;

}
//Getter and setters
}
```

And my DB's structure :

```
3ER2U0QSDTMHRdKA0eO231UCQeY2
8eJaHRU9f5ZrVogqhx0Hj1iFcgG2
     -jdhd
        -ingredients
            -0
              -nom: "bdhd"
              -quantitat: "b,bzh"
        -nom:"jdhd"
        -pasos
            -0: "djdjjd"
     -jdjd
     -jdjdvshs
AfcGeBzvdLRq19J3kRk3CVg30np2
fk39ClAVaQNFQCONU9Agp0KfUUf1addclose
```

As you can see, "pasos" is a List of String and "ingredients" is a List of Ingredient.

What I can't find out is how can I retrieve those lists from database as I want to get a List of Recepta.
I've tried a lot of things but all were wrong as it didn't retrieve any of the lists.

That's what I've tried, but i know that doesn't work because Firebase DB doesn't store lists as a List

```
final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final DatabaseReference listReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(user.getUid());
    listReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(final DataSnapshot listSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                receptas.add(listSnapshot.getValue(Recepta.class));
            }
            listReceptaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I also know that FB DB work with HashMaps but i dont know how to retrieve them or pass from a hashmap to a list without having to go through every position of hashmap

So what should I do? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the below example would help to integrate two data in one list in firebase database

```
public static ArrayList<MuteModel> muteModelList;

public void updateMuteListServer(){



    DatabaseReference frndMuteRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users/" + getFirebaseUser().getUid().trim() + "/friendlists");
    Query queryRef = frndMuteRef.orderByChild(MUTE).equalTo(YES);
    queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String,MuteModel>> t=  new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String,MuteModel>>() { };

            HashMap<String,MuteModel> hashMap= (HashMap<String,MuteModel>)dataSnapshot.getValue(t);

            if(hashMap!=null) {
               muteModelList = new ArrayList<MuteModel>(hashMap.values());
                for (MuteModel muteModel: muteModelList){
                    muteModel.setIsgroup(NO);
                }

            }else{
               muteModelList = new ArrayList<MuteModel>();


            }

            findGroupMuteList();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}

private void findGroupMuteList() {

    DatabaseReference groupMuteRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users/" + getFirebaseUser().getUid().trim() + "/"+GROUPS);
    Query queryRef = groupMuteRef.orderByChild(MUTE).equalTo(YES);
    queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String,MuteModel>> t=  new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String,MuteModel>>() { };

            HashMap<String,MuteModel> hashMap= (HashMap<String,MuteModel>)dataSnapshot.getValue(t);

            ArrayList<MuteModel> properties;
            if(hashMap!=null) {
                properties = new ArrayList<MuteModel>(hashMap.values());

                for (MuteModel muteModel:properties){
                    muteModel.setIsgroup(YES);
                }


            }else{
               properties = new ArrayList<MuteModel>();


            }

            MyChat.muteModelList.addAll(properties);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String strMuteList = gson.toJson(MyChat.muteModelList);

            editSharedPref(MUTELIST,strMuteList);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });




}
```

in your case I think the generic adapter of ingredients will look like as follows

```
GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<Ingredients>>
```

& in case of pasos you can do like

```
GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<Strings>>
```